# lzop file header structure / reading the uncompressed file size from from the lzo compressed header

Tags: java, android-studio, header, compression, lzo

I am writing an android application using java in which I need to decompress random lzo compressed files in byte arrays. I am doing that with the https://github.com/shevek/lzo-java library. The algorithm, however expects the size of the original file (uncompressed file) in order to decompress the lzo file.

```
byte[] uncompressed = new byte["Size of the uncompressed byte array which should be known before decompression"];
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("compressed byte array");
LzopInputStream us = new LzopInputStream(is);
DataInputStream ds = new DataInputStream(us);
System.out.println(ds.readByte());
ds.readFully(uncompressed);
```

I need to read the uncompressed file size from the header of the lzop compressed file. Where can I find the header structure of such files or read the decompressed file size from the header of an lzop compressed file?

(For the header, I read the first few hundred bytes, but reading them either in BIG_ENDIAN or LITTLE_ENDIAN or as shorts, Ints, and Longs -and with different beginnings for the bytes do not verify the uncompressed file size for a known file)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: please add some code, any implementation attempt, message error and/or logs so we can help you further. It is important that you show some effort before asking a question. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Marco, Thank you for your comment. I have edited the question with more details. Please let me know if you have information regarding the lzo files header structure or how to read the original file size from the compressed lzo file in Java. Thank you!